Fingerprint reader not working: Thinkpad Yoga 390 (Device is: 138a:0097)
Just got myself a Yoga 370. Tried installing Ubuntu 24.04, everything works great except the fingerprint reader cause 138a:0097 validity isn't supported.
I tried unicorn's python-validiity as a fix but the repository hasn't been maintained since the past 2 years as there's no release file.
The last update was available for 22.04 and it was working.
Is there any workaround?
In order to get the fingerprint work, I switched to Fedora 40 GNOME. It does the job, yet I would love to have Ubuntu.
For Fedora, I used taaem's python validity guess it's been maintained.
